# Python panda how to write each cell in csv to one line in text file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text

Hi I am using Python and Panda to open a csv file and tries to write it into a text file.

There is a cell appears like:

```
$AAL:
New Insider Filing on
EVP People and Communications
ELISE R EBERWEIN:
```

I want to make it like

```
$AAL: New Insider Filing on EVP People and Communications ELISE R EBERWEIN:
```

so basically for that cell to write it into one line in text file.

I have opened my file in panda:

> text = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", encoding="UTF-8")

and write it to a text file:

> text.to_csv("output.txt", index=false)

is there any thing i could do in between these two command in panda to make the cell to write into a text file in one line?

The full table is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/we3jE.jpg

Comment: can you show an actual copy of your dataframe? do each of those rows have its own index?

Comment: And a row of the input data...

Comment: It have index after I use panda to open for each row. It also have a header called ["V3"]. Full table is given in the main question now

Comment: Actual file can be downloaded here: https://ufile.io/p8psk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to replace the linebreaks '\n' in the line of interest with an empty space:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', encoding='UTF-8')
df['V3'] = df['V3'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' '))
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Doesn't really work for strip with \n. Possibility does not have endlines...
Output file looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa5o0.jpg

My code is:
` text = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")
text = text['V3'].apply(lambda x: x.strip('\n'))
print(text)
text.to_csv('output.txt', index=False) `

Comment: Misunderstood the intent.  Checkout out the code snippet; instead of applying ``lambda x: x.strip()`` you can achieve your desired outcome by replacing the linebreaks with an empty space ``lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' ')``

Comment: Hi Thanks Eric for your input, I found a way to fix this by also adding .replace('\r', ' ').replace('\n', ' ')

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.  I forgot to keep carriage return in mind.